# Installing Maximo Anywhere in different database than maximo

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere

I have Maximo installed over SQLServer and i would like to install Maximo Anywhere over DB2 are there any limitation regard this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, DB2 is fine. Other options are Oracle or MySQL.

Thanks,
M